# vis.js: How to scroll to perticular x,y coordinates on canvas?

Tags: jquery, canvas

I've used vis.js for flowchart like web based application.On click of node,the popup appears and users can fill info. in it. I've made fix height scrollable canvas. and the nodes are more than they can be aligned in fixed canvas height. Every time user fills the information, the page gets reloaded. and again user have to scroll to go to the node on which he was working before page load.
Is there any way to capture position of node and after page reload, scroll to that particular node?

I have attached image for my flowchart like application screen:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can give an unique id of each node and pass that as a GET parameter for the page reload. Then when the page is reloaded get the ID of the node of interest and use the following:

```
$('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top + 'px'
}, 'fast');
```

'fast' - speed of transition (possible values - "fast", "slow", milliseconds

Comment: But it is canvas. Would this function work on canvas?

Comment: check out this extension http://webresourcesdepot.com/jcanvas-canvas-manipulation-with-jquery/